# how to set up a tfrecords queue for seq2seq model with buckets?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to transform the inputs of [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html) about seq2seq model from placeholder to tfrecords but failed mainly because if I write all samples to a single tfrecord file I can't group samples with similar length into a same bucket, do I need to start four queues(the length of buckets) to realize it? any advice and solution is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly added [`tf.contrib.training.bucket_by_sequence_length()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/contrib.training.html#bucket_by_sequence_length) function adds support for creating multiple queues to group by bucketed sequence length, and combining the full batches in a single queue.

Comment: Thank you very much@mrry , will this function be moved out of the contrib module and become a stable API?

Comment: The API might be subject to some small changes (e.g. if we find an easier way to configure it) but the functionality will stay.